# Ignore prerelease packages in octopus deploy

Tags: nuget, octopus-deploy, semantic-versioning

In octopus deploy I would like to create a version rule on a channel that ensures that the nuget package does not have a suffix/tag on it. I have tried a regex in the "tag" section of the versioning rules but as far as I can tell, having a rule for tags only works when a tag is present. E.g. `^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$` would highlight only the version number of 1.0.0.0-tag but would not identify 1.0.0.0 if no tag is present.

Is there a way to get only packages that have no tag using the built in versioning in octopus deploy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following 'empty' regex in the Tag field:

`^$`

This will select all non-prerelease packages.